Android Credential Manager issue: NoCredentialException: During begin sign in, failure response from one tap: 16: User disabled the feature
I am using Credential Manager API for signing in users in my Android app as below:
lifecycleScope.launch {
        
        val options = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
            .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
            .setServerClientId(SERVER_CLIENT_ID)
            .setAutoSelectEnabled(false)
            .build()
        
        val request = GetCredentialRequest.Builder().addCredentialOption(options).build()
        
        val response = CredentialManager.create(requireContext())
            .getCredential(requireContext(),request)
        
        if(response.credential is CustomCredential && response.credential.type == GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL) {
            val googleCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential.createFrom(response.credential.data)
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Signed In as: ${googleCredential.id}")
            // continue with signed in...
        }
    }

This works well in a general positive scenario, but I have observed below issues in some other possible scenario:
Scenario 1: I am having multiple Google accounts signed in with different gmail ids on my device. When I disable the SignIn prompt for even a single account from device's account Settings as below:

Settings > Google >
Manage your Google Account >
Your connections to
third-party apps and services >
Settings >
Google Account sign-in prompts == Off/Disabled

.. the app keeps crashing with below exception:
androidx.credentials.exceptions.NoCredentialException: During begin sign in, failure response from one tap: 16: User disabled the feature.

In order to resolve this issue:

Changing the setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts() to true or false have no effect of app crashing in this scenario.
Clearing Google Play Services storage using dial code *#*#66382723#*#* also has no effect on this.

Any help to resolve this issue is appreciated.
Scenario 2: With the same given code, when I keep setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false), and sign in with one gmail-id at one time and sign-in with another gmail-id next time i.e. when there two accounts exists on a device with which my app can be signed-in, then, when I change configuration to auto/silent signin by changing setAutoSelectEnabled(false)
to setAutoSelectEnabled(true), the sign-in dialog hides the other gmail-ids, with which I hadn't signed-in yet and asks to choose from the two with wihch I had previously signed-in (which is expected, silent signin won't work as per official docs now, but). Now after choosing to sign-in with any of these gmail-ids, when I sign out by calling clearCredentialState() and try to sign-in again next time, it again prompts to choose from the same gmail-ids.
(And in-order to dissociate/revoke a gmail-id to be used for silent sign-in in my app, when I manually remove my app from connected third party apps from the google account settings, it ends me up in the Scenario 1.)
Any help to dissociate/revoke a gmail-id from being used for silent sign-in in my app is appreciated.

(1) To answer your first question: the current implementation of that setting is that if a user has disabled the sign-in prompt for at least one account, it will be completely disabled for all accounts. The rationale behind that was giving the ability to the user to disable that feature as a whole without forcing them to go throw each account one by one to disable that. I understand that this might seem counter-intuitive; we will discuss that internally to see if we would want to change that behavior and will add a comment when we have reached a decision.
(2) To answer your second question, let me go through a relatively detailed explanation so other users can also benefit from this in case they come across the same issue; I'll explain the two parameters set through adding setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true|false) and setAutoSelectEnabled(true|false) and what happens when you call clearCredentialState() and when these parameters play a role.
Let's say you have 3 Google accounts on your device and you have set the setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false). Then, regardless of what you set for setAutoSelectEnabled(), and regardless of which account(s) you had used in the past to sign-in to the app, whenever you call the APIs, you will see all three accounts in the picker. Things start getting more interesting when you use setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true). Let's say you had used accounts 1 and 2 in the past to sign the into the app. You may have noticed that the first time you use a google account to sign into an app, it prompts the user to give permission to share certain basic information of the user with the app (name, email, profile picture, ..). If user grants that permission, then sign-in happens. Since you had used accounts 1 and 2 in the past to sign in, it means that the user has "authorized" sharing of those info with the app for accounts 1 and 2. So if the API is called while setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true) is set, only those two accounts will appear in the picker; we are basically filtering out the account(s) that have not given the authorization to share their data. If at this point you call clearCredentialState(), nothing changes since all that api call does is effectively "signing you out of the app", it doesn't revoke the permissions that were granted earlier.
To complete the discussion, let me now explain what the setAutoSelectEnabled(true|false) does in general. If this is called with false, there is basically no change in behaviour in general. Setting that by passing true can make a difference if

You could see only one item in the picker if you had not set the setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
The only selection that you could see had already given the authorization to share those info with the app (in case of Google accounts).

If both of these are met, then setting setAutoSelectEnabled(true) can have an impact: if clearCredentialState() was not called immediately before, then user will be auto signed-in to the app when the API is called. To give a couple of examples to clarify this, consider these:
Example 1.  Imagine the case of having 3 Google accounts on the device where you have only used Account 1 to sign into the app. Then if we use setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false), you will see all three accounts. If you use setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true), you only see Account 1 in the picker. If you set setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true) and setAutoSelectEnabled(true), then you won't see the picker and user is auto signed-in using Account 1. Now at this point, if you call clearCredentialState() and keep setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true) and setAutoSelectEnabled(true), you can't auto sign-in since you practically signed-out the user, so you will see Account 1 in the picker. In fact, in this case, if you choose to continue with that account, the system will not show you the screen that asks for permissions to share the data with the app; that permission is still there in the system so it skips that step.
Example 2. Imagine the case of having 3 Google accounts where you have used Accounts 1 and 2 to sign into the app. Then if we use setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false), you will see all three accounts. If you use setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true), you only see Accounts 1 and 2 in the picker. If you set setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true) and setAutoSelectEnabled(true), then you still see both accounts in the picker, regardless of what you set for setAutoSelectEnabled() since you have more than one "qualified/authorized" credentials so the system doesn't know which one to pick to sign you in automatically.
Sorry for the lengthy explanation, please let us know if you have further questions.

thanks for your answer. I would be looking forward for if anything changes for if user has turned off the Google Accounts sign-in prompts because we were relying on the Google SignIn for SSO for our current userbase. Disabling sign-in prompt not only prevents from signing in from other available accounts on the device, it also prevents signing-in to all the third party apps, I mean, this setting is also not app specific to restrict the particular apps which abuses it. Is there any alternative to the Choose an account picker BottomSheet to still use GoogleSignIn on Android?

For the 2nd scenario: it clarifies now that clearCredentialState() effectively signs out but doesn't revoke the permission. Revoking permission is not the thing which I am looking for but to get the ability to achieve the auto sign-in functionality similar to the silentSignIn with lastSignedInAccount api of google-auth.

(contd)... if user is currently logged in with one account and had signed out from the rest authorized accounts.

For (1), I will add more comments when we have more to share; note that we also have a per-app mechanism to prevent abuse: if a user cancels the picker three times in a row (in Android 13 and below), we will not show the bottomsheet for 24 hrs to avoid an app spamming users with that; that is per app mechanism. For (2), most apps maintain their "signed-in state" internally after the user signs in for the first time; that is something you might want to look into as well.

I have been preferring to rely on Google SignIn alone as single source of truth and for credential storage/validations, instead of implementing by own, provided that user data is already there of the same google-id, but not the values which prove authority to use them. "Along with ability to signIn in last signed in account despite of multiple authorized accounts"

Hi, @AliNaddaf Could you please clarify that why in below scenario GoogleSign-in sent me "nocredentialexception" ?

Test case: I have remove all Google Account from mobile & try to sign in that time Exception return.
Core: .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
.setAutoSelectEnabled(false)


If there are no Google accounts on the device, then it means there are no credentials that it can present to the user, hence NoCredentialException, regardless of the values you set for the fiter or auto-select. What behavior did you expect?

@AliNaddaf can we enable Add account option  in the bottom sheet UI?

No, for two reasons: the bottomsheet flow is a generic authentication UI, covering Google ID token option AND passkeys and username/passwords, all at the same time in the same UI so showing Add Account is not appropriate (since that only applies to Google accounts). Secondly, the Add Account flow is not a quick flow; it has multiple steps and the bottomsheet flow (also known as OneTap) tries to be as close to a "One Tap Authentication" as possible, so adding a flow that is considerably longer and more complex into that flow is not preferred.

@AliNaddaf - can you please answer this one - https://stackoverflow.com/q/78937929/1363471
