What's the latest approach for Google Sign-in and authorize an android jetpack app to access users Google Drive data?
I am writing an android jetpack app in kotlin; and the app

has NO backend server
should use the latest recommended Android Credential Manager API and Authenticate users with Sign in with Google for user authentication
should be authorized to access user's Google Drive data and for it the app should use Authorize access to user data on Android
AuthorizationRequest has a requestOfflineAccess(String serverClientId) method, which returns an authorizationCode. This code can be exchanged with Google Token endpoint for refresh and access tokens. But is it safe to do in an android app? Remember, this app has no backend
and should also obtain refresh and access tokens
should use Credential to refresh the access token when it expires using a refresh token.
and the last, but not the least, how the refresh tokens, access tokens, CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET be securely saved in the android app

Can someone show a complete end to end example or guide on an approach  that takes care of all these requirements and uses the latest recommendations from Google to authenticate (sign-in) the user and authorize the app to access user's Google Drive data?
Different examples on the web use different apis and most of them are deprecated now. There is no complete end to end example and the documentation from Google, despite being lot, still is not complete; it itself recommends and points to deprecated apis.

The documentation covers this: https://developers.google.com/identity

@MartinZeitler AuthorizationRequest has a requestOfflineAccess(String serverClientId) method, which returns an authorizationCode. This code can be exchanged with Google Token endpoint for refresh and access tokens. But is it safe to do in an android app? Remember, this app has no backend

The documentation is written for apps with a backend. What about an app with no backend or now Google has totally deprecated such apps? Without requestOfflineAccess, I only get a short lived access token. How will this token be refreshed without a refresh token and a backend? Re-authorizing (even programmatically) will get a new access token but re-authorization is different from  token refresh, no? I may soon hit an api limit with re-authorization

Requesting off-site resources is off-topic: "Can someone show a complete end to end example/github project which combines all these approaches", while the required HTTP redirect likely cannot be found on GitHub. This simply isn't how it works.

I edited the question to show an example or guidance on how to cater in all the requirements. Or may be point out that what I am looking for is not possible at all with the developers.google.com/identity libraries

When the API demands an oAuth flow, you are not in the position to state the requirements, which may have nothing in common with the given reality.  Just see the relevant documentation, incl. sample app: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/android-api-deprecation
